# Mounting a part of Hdfs using HDFS Nfs Gateway

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, nfs, hortonworks-data-platform

1.I am trying to mount HDFS to a local directory using NFS Gateway,I was successful in mounting the root "/",What i want to achieve is mounting only a part of HDFS (say /user) on local file system is there any way by which this can be done

2.Also i want to know how to mount HDFS on a separate machine,not part of the cluster,what i ideally want is a machine acting as NFS drive on which i have mounted a part of HDFS and all client uploading the file to that remote directory

i am using Hortonworks vm 2.2 ,Any suggestion would be very helpul